# Load jquery min inside function

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to load the jquery inside the function, the other function is working but when I declare the jquery like this

```
wp_register_script( 'jquery', plugins_url('js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'), '', true); // v1.10.1
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
```

It is not working, Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to include the jquery, because its already declared in wordpress. This is how you insert the jquery into the theme or admin panel, but as i see on the code you can do it like this example

```
wp_register_script( 
    'mycustom', 
    plugins_url('js/jquery_custom.js', __FILE__ ), 
    array('jquery'), 
    '', 
    true
);
```

where `array('jquery')` means your included files required `jquery` and when you call the handler through `wp_enqueue_script( 'mycustom' );`  its automatic load the jquery.

Take a look on the documentation of [wp_register_script()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script)